# JAVA \ Compile a function only on runtime

Tags: java, jvm, runtime, jit

My code is used as part of two big versions and interact with external interface.
In one of the versions new API was added (I need to call a new method).

I would like to prevent maintaining two versions of my code, and use if statement:

```
If VersionX
   Do Method1()
If VersionY
   Do Method2()
```

assuming `method2()` is the new function I need to call, is there a way that the code can compile only on runtime (means that if I run on `VersionX` system, there would be no problem of compilation and exceptions though `method 2()` does not exist there)?

Comment: you can check if the method is present in the interface by `interfaceClass.class.getMethod("xxx", params)` and catch the exception. Alternatively you can just call the method and catch LinkageError (NoSuchMethodError) (set a static boolean and do no call the method any more, depending on the value)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with an interface and two classes:

```
interface API {
    void Method();
}

class APIX implements API {
    void Method() {
        someInstance.Method1();
    }
}

class APIY implements API {
    void Method() {
        anotherInstance.Method2();
    }
}
```

Then depending on the current version, you create an instance of either *APIX* or *APIY*:

```
API api;
if (isVersionX) 
    api = new APIX();
else
    api = new APIY();
api.Method();
```

This code is compiled against the newer API wich contains both methods. Since class loading is on demand only, the class using the newer method is not loaded when only the old API is available and you don't have any conflicts at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to call the method if it exists.

```
// calls a method if it exists or throws an exception.
Method method = object.getClass().getMethod("DoMethod1");
method.invoke(object);
```

Comment: another great idea, I would try that too! Thanks!